# python script doesn't work on startup on raspberry pi 4

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I read about how to run a script on startup. 
the instructions were quite clear and easy.

I opened rc.local using the following command:
**sudo nano /etc/rc.local**

and the I add this line in it:
**sudo python3 /Desktop/dnp3-v1.2/dnp3/rtu.py &**

the content of rc.locale is now like this:

```
_IP=$(hostname -I) || true
if [ "$_IP" ]; then
  printf "My IP address is %s\n" "$_IP"
fi
sudo python3 /Desktop/dnp3-v1.2/dnp3/rtu.py &
exit 0
```

but the script doesn't run on startup. I'm using rpi 4 and raspbian.
any suggestion would be appreciated. tnx

**EDIT :**
I found something else:
sudo nano /home/pi/.bashrc
I put the **echo Running at boot** and **sudo python3 /Desktop/dnp3-v1.2/dnp3/rtu.py** in there, I see a new error, when I open the terminal it give me some dependency error. but I already installed all dependencies using **pip3 install 'dependency'**, when I run the code in terminal it worked fine, but in startup it shows the errors

**EDIT 2:**
I installed all dependencies again using `sudo su` and then running `sudo pip3 install 'dependency'`, now I see this: **Traceback (most recent call last): File "/...", line 20, in  ser=serial.Serial( NameError: name 'serial' is not defined**

Comment: What is the output of `sudo pip3 install 'dependency'`? Do not forget to start with `sudo`.

Comment: @isydmr something like '... it's already satisfied ...' which means it's installed

Comment: It still sounds like you're missing a dependency (the `serial` module, provided by the `python-serial` or `python3-serial` package, if you're installing using `apt`, or by `pyserial` if you're installing with `pip`).

Comment: @larsks if the dependency was not installed, then how is it possible that the code works when I run it in the terminal manually ?!